# DevExpress Pass two keys to LookupFor DataSource request on LoadUrl

Tags: c#, devexpress, devextreme

I Have two column for key in table but I cant find any way to pass them both...

This is my element

```
<div class="form-inline">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StreetCode)
        <div class="form-inline formGroup">
            @(Html.DevExtreme().LookupFor(m => m.StreetCode).ID("StreetCodeId")
                                                   .DataSource(d => d.RemoteController()
                                                   .LoadUrl("/look/Streets")
                                                   .Key("CodeStreet"))
                                                   .ValueExpr("CodeStreet")
                                                   .DisplayExpr("Street")
                                                   .Width("100%")
                                                   .Value(Model.StreetCode))
            <span asp-validation-for="StreetCode" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my method

```
   public IActionResult Streets(DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions)
    {
        return Json(DataSourceLoader.Load(DB.Table, loadOptions));      
    }
```

When I execute it I get
[image]

I   get the right key for street

When I try to pass two keys I got

like `.Key("CodeStreet","CityCode"))`

for example

```
<div class="form-inline">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StreetCode)
        <div class="form-inline formGroup">
            @(Html.DevExtreme().LookupFor(m => m.StreetCode).ID("StreetCodeId")
                                                   .DataSource(d => d.RemoteController()
                                                   .LoadUrl("/look/Streets")
                                                   .Key("CodeStreet","CityCode"))
                                                   .ValueExpr("CodeStreet")
                                                   .DisplayExpr("Street")
                                                   .Width("100%")
                                                   .Value(Model.StreetCode))
            <span asp-validation-for="StreetCode" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I got

this :

[image]

How do I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress does not support composite keys to my knowledge. Take a look at this [thread](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t751301/datagrid-how-to-use-a-lookup-column-with-a-composite-key).

You can also override the `onLoad` and pass the keys through a URL parameter.